# Does rocksdbjava api library contain the rocksdb database itself

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

I am very new to rockdb and will be using the rocksdb in my application as a lookup service. Does the rockDBjava library api provided contain the database itself, I mean is it not necessary to install rocksDB database separately.

I tried running the code using library and see some files created in the db path I mentioned in code, so not sure how exactly it works and if I need to install DB separately or if the library stores data in the directory and it itself acts as database?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not need to install RocksDB separately if you already have RocksJava working.  They're not very clear on stating that, but if you look at the [wiki in their Git repo](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksJava-Basics) you'll find this:

> RocksJava is structured in 3 layers:
>
> 1. The Java classes within the org.rocksdb package which form the
>      RocksJava API. Java users only directly interact with this layer.
> 2. JNI code written in C++ that provides the link between the Java API
>      and RocksDB.
> 3. RocksDB itself written in C++ and compiled into a native library which
>      is used by the JNI layer.

That third point is basically their way of saying that RocksDB itself is one of the layers of RocksJava.